# Hiding cloud services for VPN access only

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have a single Azure cloud service that is accessible externally. I would like to restrict access to it only from inside of my organization. I have setup a virtual network between azure and my organization and configured my cloud service to use that virtual network.  The only problem now is how do I restrict an external access to my services. This seems that it should be easy to do but I cannot straightforward solution. Am I missing something here?

Thank You!

Comment: When you say *external access*, do you mean via the computers in your local data center on-premises that go across a VPN tunnel, or do you mean a computer connecting via public Internet where you want to only allow specific source IP addresses through?

Comment: I would like to restrict access from any public internet and allow access from local data center on-premises that go across a VPN tunnel.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The real fix just got released on Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-internal-overview/

Comment: I do not understand why you just unaccepted my answer and marked your own answer (this answer, which is nothing but a link) as the accepted answer. At best, this is a comment on my answer, or an edit. *Link-only answers are not answers.* And this is about the internal load balancer and does not specifically answer your original question. So, basically, you unmarked my answer, and gave yourself an accepted answer, one that doesn't answer the original question and is link-only. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 4):

A point-to-point VPN connection should let you connect directly from your on-prem network to your Azure VM's without having a public endpoint. You'd now need to manage your own load-balancing since you'd have direct access to each VM within a deployment. This would be a secure connection, and only traffic over the VPN would be able to reach any of the VMs (again, assuming you didn't have any public endpoints on the cloud service).

From a public-internet perspective, you'd need public endpoints. Those endpoints on a Virtual Machine may be protected with ACL's (access control lists), which are IP allow/block ranges. For example: Here's a VM with port 7474 open publicly. Notice the **MANAGE ACL** button circled at the bottom.
[image]

Choosing this, you may now enter an ordered list of IP allow/block ranges. Here, I'm just opening an IP range from my imaginary office building:

[image]

At this point, only addresses 1.2.3.x would be able to connect via this endpoint.

Note: Among the IP ranges, you could also include the public VIP for one of your other cloud services.

Comment: Endpoints tab does not seem to be available for the Cloud Services.  Is there an easy way around this?

Comment: Right now, acl's are just on virtual machines.